# Position issue with image gallery on top of fixed navbar on paralax site

Tags: css, positioning, fixed, image-gallery, navbar

This is my first time using this site, I hear you guys are amazing.

I am a rather new web designer / developer.

This is the plugin I am using for a a image gallery on a site. 
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/20/responsive-image-gallery/

I have this image gallery on a portion of my paralax scrolling site.

The navbar is fixed up top and when scrolling up. the SELECTED thumbnail goes under the fixed navbar just fine. but everything else is ontop of it.

I have tried adjusting all sorts of CSS positioning.

I am honestly having troubles phrasing this question.

Can anyone suggest anything please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your navbar is set to

```
postion:fixed
```

Meaning that it is positioned relative to the browser, not the page. In which case, you should also set:

```
z-index: 2
```

... or 4, 5, or whatever, as long as it's higher than the z-index of everything you want to go 'below' it when scrolling.

Comment: I've always been afraid of z-index, mostly because I don't understand it lol